# Vue.js proxy for CORS not functioning correctly

Tags: javascript, vue.js, cors

I'm making a Vue.js front-end which needs to communicate with an API also running on localhost.

I'm usng the axios module to send my post request.

I can't set headers in the back-end because it's not mine.

I already tried setting up a proxy using the following code.

This is the content of my vue.config.js file:

```
module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        proxy: {
            '/login': {
                target: 'https://localhost/api/login',
                changeOrigin: true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I make the request like this.

```
created() {
    axios({
      method: 'post',
      url: '/login',
      headers: {"content-type": "application/json"},
      data: {
        User: {
          "login_id": "admin",
          "password": "xxx"
        }
      }
    }).then(res => console.log(res.data)).catch(err => console.log(err.response))
  }
```

With the proxy I don't get a CORS error anymore but I get a 401 unauthorized, which doesn't make sense because the information supplied is correct. I tested this using postman and it was a valid request.
This is the request from my postman export:

```
{
    "info": {
        "_postman_id": "xxx",
        "name": "Biostar",
        "schema": "https://schema.getpostman.com/json/collection/v2.1.0/collection.json"
    },
    "item": [
        {
            "name": "Log In",
            "request": {
                "method": "POST",
                "header": [],
                "body": {
                    "mode": "raw",
                    "raw": "{\r\n  \"User\": {\r\n    \"login_id\": \"admin\",\r\n    \"password\": \"xxx\"\r\n  }\r\n}",
                    "options": {
                        "raw": {
                            "language": "json"
                        }
                    }
                },
                "url": {
                    "raw": "https://localhost/api/login",
                    "protocol": "https",
                    "host": [
                        "localhost"
                    ],
                    "path": [
                        "api",
                        "login"
                    ]
                }
            },
            "response": []
        }
}
```

So I set up an express.js server to output the body and the headers.
This is the result when I call the server from my front-end:

```
{ User: { login_id: 'admin', password: 'xxx' } }
{
  host: 'localhost:9000',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '44',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Chromium";v="88", "Google Chrome";v="88", ";Not A Brand";v="99"',
  accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'sec-ch-ua-mobile': '?0',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/88.0.4324.146 Safari/537.36',
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  origin: 'http://localhost:8080',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-site',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  referer: 'http://localhost:8080/',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'accept-language': 'nl-NL,nl;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.7'
}
```

This is the result from the request sent with postman:

```
{ User: { login_id: 'admin', password: 'xxx' } }
{
  'content-type': 'application/json',
  'user-agent': 'PostmanRuntime/7.26.5',
  accept: '*/*',
  'postman-token': 'xxx',
  host: 'localhost:9000',
  'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  connection: 'keep-alive',
  'content-length': '81'
}
```

Comment: You can't bypass CORS without a proxy. That would defeat the object of CORS.

Comment: Probably the issue is that the request you put together with postman is different to the one you put together with JS, but there isn't enough information in the question to tell how.

Comment: Might the problem be that my front-end is running on http and the back-end runs on https?

Comment: I added a json export from postman of my request

Comment: That looks the same. I'd add some debugging logic to the back end, even though it isn't yours, it is local, so you should be able to get in and make changes so  you want see what is different about the two requests from the server's perspective. That or see if the Vue proxy is outputting any debug information when the request fails.

Comment: The back-end I'm talking about is a dashboard I installed using an .exe file and isn't open source. I don't know how to start adding debug information to this.

Comment: Ick. That makes things trickier. I'd build a test server with Express.js that just dumps the headers and body to a file.

Comment: I am done setting up the express.js server and I added the results of the requests to the question